# What are the stages of flavor development/aging for a brettanomyces apple cider?

Tags: cider, brettanomyces

Recipe:

- 1 gallon apple
- juice yeast: WLP648
- lemon juice
- wine tannin
- nutrients (not staggered)
- OG: 1.048
- Pitched yeast at 70f but I turned it up to 80f after a couple days

After 2 weeks, the gravity is 1.003. I call this "done" fermenting but wondering how long to wait and what am I waiting for? The cider is currently pretty clean tasting, I don't think I sense any brettness. Will that develop if I let it sit in primary or secondary? I understand that brett can ferment pretty clean when used in primary and that adding it in secondary can get some more funk/earthiness (too late for that).

I'm just generally wondering if I should let this sit but also I'm trying to avoid letting it sit for X months just to find out it tastes the same. I'm looking for something funky and earthy.